# how to reduce the size of image with out reducing height and width in ios?

Tags: ios

Please guide me. how to reduce the size of image with out reducing height and width in ios?

I will take a photo through device camera. the size around 250kb. Now I want to reduce 100KB without resizing the height and width.

Is it possible to do it?

Please Share your views.

Comment: you are looking at downsampling functionality: did u check if it is already provided by coreImage?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the jpg image to jpeg will reduce size. Try this.

```
[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.01f)];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Happy Coding...**

***Please use this logic which does not reduce file Quality and also not reduce the image height width.***

**Without losing image quality you can perform the better enhancement.**

Here you need to manage **maxByte** based on your requirement.

It also releases memory after performing this enhancement.

Here is the **UIImage Extention**...

```
extension UIImage {
func resize(fileName: String, maxByte: Int = 800000, folderName: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            guard let currentImageSize = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)?.count else { return }//completion(nil) }
            
            var imageSize = currentImageSize
            var percentage: CGFloat = 1.0
            var generatedImage: UIImage? = self
            let percantageDecrease: CGFloat = imageSize < 10000000 ? 0.1 : 0.3
            while imageSize > maxByte && percentage > 0.5 {
                print("Performing \(percentage)")
                let canvas = CGSize(width: self.size.width * percentage,
                                    height: self.size.height * percentage)
                let format = self.imageRendererFormat
                format.opaque = false
                generatedImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: canvas, format: format).image {
                    _ in self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvas))
                }
                guard let generatedImageSize = generatedImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)?.count else { return }//completion(nil) }
                imageSize = generatedImageSize
                percentage -= percantageDecrease
            }
         
            completion(generatedImage)
        }
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use this function for compression of images on iOS that I found on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7409933/643109).

```
+ (NSData*)imageDataWithCGImage:(CGImageRef)CGimage UTType:(const CFStringRef)imageUTType desiredCompressionQuality:(CGFloat)desiredCompressionQuality
{
    NSData* result = nil;

    CFMutableDataRef destinationData = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    CGImageDestinationRef destinationRef = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(destinationData, imageUTType, 1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destinationRef, (CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:desiredCompressionQuality], (NSString*)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality, nil]);
    if (destinationRef != NULL)
    {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destinationRef, CGimage, NULL);

        if (CGImageDestinationFinalize(destinationRef))
        {
            result = [NSData dataWithData:(NSData*)destinationData];
        }
    }
    if (destinationData)
    {
        CFRelease(destinationData);
    }
    if (destinationRef)
    {
        CFRelease(destinationRef);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The image type can be kUTTypePNG, but the quality parameter most likely will not work. It also can be kUTTypeJPEG2000 for your needs.