# How to reduce filter image size in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, image, memory

I am using swift to develop a image filter view. User can capture a image by camera or select one image from image library. Then my app will create 8 filter images based on that image and show them to the user. User can select one of the filter image to show on a bigger image view. Below is the code to generate filter image. If the image is large, my app will create a few large filter images which cause memory usage increate. Is there a way to reduce the size of the filter image?

```
func outputImage(filter: CIFilter, originalImage: UIImage) -> UIImage{
    let inputImage = CIImage(image: originalImage)
    filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let cgImage = context!.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, fromRect: (filter.outputImage?.extent)!)
    return UIImage(CGImage: cgImage, scale: 1, orientation: originalImage.imageOrientation)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce the image size you can use:

```
newImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image: UIImage, compressionQuality: CGfloat)
```

Comment: I have tried this method but it still not solve my problem. May be it doesn't relate to the size of the image. It may be caused by something else.

Comment: Check this post, and let me know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137488/how-do-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-reduce-upload-image-size