# Memory Problems with UIImage(contentsOfFile)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I have a Collection View where i load some Images from my documents directory:

```
func reloadNotesFromStore() {
    {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TaskDraw")

        let formsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "task_id = %@", self.task_id)
        fetchRequest.predicate = formsPredicate

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

        self.photos.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let taskDrawings = (try! context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as! [TaskDraw]

        let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL

        for taskDraw in taskDrawings {

            let imageFilename = "\(taskDraw.remoteID!)_combined.png"
            let imageFullPath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(self.task_id)/\(imageFilename)")

            // create combined image to display
            let photo = Photo(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFullPath.path!)!)

            photo.selected = false
            photo.taskDraw = taskDraw

            self.photos.append(photo)
        }

        } ~> {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Every time when ill display my CollectionViewController, my Memory usage increases by about 30 MB.

The images that i load with UIImage(contentsOfFile) are about 150 kb.

Ok tried no Leos Solution, but still no success. When ill reload my Controller (modally) my memory always increases about 30-40 Mbytes.

```
func reloadNotesFromStore() {
    {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "TaskDraw")

        let formsPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "task_id = %@", self.task_id)
        fetchRequest.predicate = formsPredicate

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors

        self.items.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        let taskDrawings = (try! context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)) as! [TaskDraw]

        let path = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0] as NSURL

        for taskDraw in taskDrawings {

            let imageFilename = "\(taskDraw.remoteID!)_combined.png"
            let imageFullPath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(self.task_id)/\(imageFilename)")

            // create combined image to display
            let collectionViewItem = CollectionViewItem()
            collectionViewItem.filePath = imageFullPath
            collectionViewItem.selected = false
            collectionViewItem.taskDraw = taskDraw

            self.items.append(collectionViewItem)
        }

        } ~> {
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PhotoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCell

    let item = items[indexPath.item]

    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: item.filePath!.path!)!
    .....
```

How can i force Swift to release my memory? 
Update2:

When ill use UIImage(named: ..) instead of UIImage(contentsOfFile: ....) then on first init the memory increase by about 40 Mbyte, but stays when ill dismiss the View and load it again (i guess this happens because named: .. caches the image)

But this also do not release the memory when ill dismiss the VC.

Comment: don't load them to memory. all you need is an array with the urls/paths

Comment: So you mean i should only store the filenames, and load the image then cellForItemAtIndexPath? But why is my photo array not being released when ill dismiss the ViewController?

Comment: yes get the image when preparing your cell

Comment: OK thanks for that answer. Ill already thought about that - but i was not sure why the memory is not beeing released when ill dismiss the viewController. And still why do iOS need up to 30 Mbyte of Ram for displaying 3-4 Images (with about 150kb) - i will try that out.

Comment: Do you think its a good idea to load only Thumbnails when ill use a collectionView? My Images are in with a size of 2048x1536 px - or does that make not any (huge) difference?

Comment: Thumbnails will make it load much faster

Comment: Thanks Leo for your explanation! Feel free to provide this as answer, i would accept it then. Thanks!!

Comment: first try it out than let me know the outcome

Comment: Ok - so to load it without any delay i should create my images also as thumbnail? Already when ill create them, or can i do this when ill load my items from store?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29138120/2303865

Comment: Ok edited my answer, but still the same problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i fixed the problem now with the following solution:

I still create an UIImage in Memory, like this:

```
for taskDraw in taskDrawings {

       let imageFilename = "\(taskDraw.remoteID!)_combined.png"
       let imageFullPath = path.URLByAppendingPathComponent("\(self.task_id)/\(imageFilename)")

       let photo = Photo(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageFullPath.path!)!.resizeToWidth(300))
       photo.taskDraw = taskDraw
       photo.addNote = false
       self.photos.append(photo)
```

So only show the resized image in the CollectionView. (Otherwise i need to store a Thumbnail on Disk)

And:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.photos.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
}
```

In Controller.

Now, the Memory consumption is quite lower AND after dismissing my ViewController, the used memory is now released.

Answer (score 0):

I have a image in Document directory , I am using UIImage(contentsOfFile:) method to make the UIImage, image exist in DocumentDirectory but method return nil.

```
  let img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: ChatUtils.getPathWithFolderName(kChatAttachmentOriginalFolderName) + ("/" + fileName))
```

Comment: This is not an answer.