# ios compress image to target size (not CGSize)

Tags: ios, uiimage, compression

How to compress image to a target size (not CGSize) like 10MB to 9MB?
Do I have to resize the image?
Tried `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`, not very useful.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137488/how-do-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-reduce-upload-image-size

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resize the UIImage to reduce upload image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137488/how-do-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-reduce-upload-image-size)

Answer (score 0):

To decrease image size, you must decrease its size or Quality. for quality you can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with quality in second parameter.

to downscale you can use code from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137488/how-do-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-reduce-upload-image-size