# how to reduce photo size and send to myserver in parameters in swift4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

i'm using the `UIImagePickerController` to take photo and im converting image to base64 and i want to send image to my server but the photo was converting to base64 but the problem is i can't send the converted photo to my server in paramenter

here my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var CameraOutlet: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Complaint_Image1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Complaint_Image2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Complaint_Image3: UIImageView!


func TakePhotos() {
    let Image = UIImagePickerController()
    Image.allowsEditing = true
    Image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
    Image.delegate = self

    present(Image, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let picture = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        if (Complaint_Image1.image != nil && Complaint_Image2.image != nil) {
            Complaint_Image3.image = picture
        }
        else if Complaint_Image1.image != nil {
            Complaint_Image2.image = picture
        }
        else {
            Complaint_Image1.image = picture
        }
    }

    if Complaint_Image1.image != nil {
        let imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(Complaint_Image1.image!)! as NSData
        let imageStr = imageData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let imageBase64 = imageStr
        let imgstr2 = String.init(format: "data:image/png;base64,%@", imageBase64)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(imgstr2, forKey: "image")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    let picture1 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "image")
    let parameter = ["Image1": picture1!,"Image":[["name": picture2],["name": picture3]] as [String: Any]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resize the UIImage to reduce upload image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137488/how-do-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-reduce-upload-image-size)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift ios reduce image size before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256005/swift-ios-reduce-image-size-before-upload)

Comment: Bro I’m taking the photo and I want to send in parameter can u pls write  code for me where I should use it and how can I send in parameters

Comment: @user9772943, what actually you want? Want to reduce photo size? or want to know how to send it as parameter?

Comment: Both firstly reduce photo size and convert to base64 where I should use and how to send the reduce size of image with coverted to base64 send in parameters my code is top

Comment: Guys plz help me out this problem

Comment: @user9772943 there are at least two other questions that address exactly the problem from the title of your question.

Comment: Okay.. what should I keep bro

Comment: @user9772943, did you tried answer?

Comment: Just a min checking now

Comment: bro how can i send the conveted image in parameter in my code. and my server needs base64 this format "data:image/png;base64,%@" how can i? . show me in my code plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` `compressionQuality`to reduce photo size.

```
let picture = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

// USE ANY OF 1 FROM BELOW TO REDUCE SIZE    
let imgData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 1.0)
print("1.0 size is: \(String(describing: Double((imgData1?.count)!) / 1024.0)) KB")

let imgData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 0.7)
print("0.7 size is: \(String(describing: Double((imgData2?.count)!) / 1024.0)) KB")

let imgData3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 0.4)
print("0.4 size is: \(String(describing: Double((imgData3?.count)!) / 1024.0)) KB")

let imgData4 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(picture, 0.0)
print("0.0 size is: \(String(describing: Double((imgData4?.count)!) / 1024.0)) KB")

// BASE64 STRING
let img1stBase64: String = (imgData2?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))!
let img2ndBase64: String = (imgData3?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))!
let img3rdBase64: String = (imgData4?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))!

let parameter = ["Image1": img1stBase64,"Image":[["name": img2ndBase64],["name": img3rdBase64]]] as [String: Any]
```

**OUTPUT**

Here you can clearly know the difference between originalImage size and reduced image size from below.

```
1.0 size is: 3177.0869140625 KB
0.7 size is: 892.78125 KB
0.4 size is: 363.2890625 KB
0.0 size is: 180.8818359375 KB
```

Comment: I heard size gets increased after encoding to base64, how to check size after converting to base64?

Answer (score 2):

Just use following code to compress image before upload to server side

First of all, add below extension of uiimage to any class or singleton class

```
extension UIImage {

//MARK:- convenience function in UIImage extension to resize a given image
func convert(toSize size:CGSize, scale:CGFloat) ->UIImage {
    let imgRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x:0.0, y:0.0), size: size)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
    self.draw(in: imgRect)
    let copied = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return copied!
    }
}
```

and then write below methods in controller where pick images

```
//MARK:- ImagePicker Delegate Methods

internal func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    // resize our selected image
    let resizedImage = chosenImage.convert(toSize:CGSize(width:100.0, height:100.0), scale: UIScreen.main.scale)
    profileImg.image = resizedImage
    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: OP wants to reduce Photo size not photo.