# UIImageJPEGRepresentation increases UIImage size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I've an image *(captureImage)* which is taken by *camera* and resized. I use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to compress image, after the compression, image's size is increased. Is it normal behaviour or I'm doing compression/resizing in wrong way?

```
if let image = captureImage {
    print(image.size) // (700, 700)
    let compressedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3)!
    let compressedImage = UIImage(data: compressedImageData)!
    print(compressedImage.size) // (3024, 3024)
}
```

Comment: Please refer to bellow link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137488/how-do-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-reduce-upload-image-size May be helpful for you.

Comment: Did you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this code is for image compression

```
  let compressedImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3)!
```

One way for getting the file size is by saving into document directory.
For example -

```
  let filePath = fileURL
        var fileSize : UInt64

        do {
            //return [FileAttributeKey : Any]
            let attr = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath.path)
            fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64

            //if you convert to NSDictionary, you can get file size old way as well.
            let dict = attr as NSDictionary
            fileSize = dict.fileSize()
            print(fileSize)

        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
```