# Scaling an array of UIImages to a specified percentage causes UI to be unresponsive for a couple of seconds?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Currently I have 2 arrays of high-res `UIImages` that I am trying to scale down to 30% of its original resolution and reload its contents in a `UITableView`. I am using the extension below from Leo Dabus [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29138120/2303865) to scale down the images:

```
extension UIImage {
    func resized(withPercentage percentage: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let canvasSize = CGSize(width: size.width * percentage, height: size.height * percentage)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(canvasSize, false, scale)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: canvasSize))
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}
```

When `viewWillAppear` is called, I loop through both arrays, and scale each image in the arrays down to 30%, then reload the table view like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        for index in 0..<self.arrayOne.count
        {
            self.arrayOne[index].image = self.arrayOne[index].image?.resized(withPercentage: 0.3)
        }

        for index in 0..<self.arrayTwo.count
        {
            self.arrayTwo[index].image = self.arrayTwo[index].image?.resized(withPercentage: 0.3)
        }   
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    ...

    let cellImage = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    var image: UIImage = UIImage()

    if test1 == true
    {
        if let theImage = arrayOne[index].image
        {
            image = theImage
        }        
    }
    else
    {
        if let theImage = arrayTwo[index].image
        {
            image = theImage
        }
    }

    cellImage.image = image

    return cell
}
```

All the data of my table view loads just fine when `viewWillAppear` is called, but there is a 2-3 second delay where the whole UI freezes, and nothing is responsive to touches. After that delay, the responsiveness reappears and is ok.

I'm sure it has to do with my scaling function performing heavy work each time it has to scale a high-res image down, causing the UI to be unresponsive momentarily, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

How can I resolve this initial UI unresponsive issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Problem is connected with DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk what should be done instead?

Comment: You should do this in background thread and after all scaling is done call reload table view from main thread

Comment: `UIImageView` will automatically handle scaling for you, based on the `contentMode`, and will handle lots of corner cases for you automatically. Why are you manually scaling the images? This looks like you're scaling down 70% every time the view appears, which seems very likely to cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of freezing is that main thread is used for maintaining UI, and if you run hard calculations in it it will freeze your app.
So you should run your loops in background like in snippet, and after ending update your UI in main thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    for index in 0..<self.arrayOne.count
    {
        self.arrayOne[index].image = self.arrayOne[index].image?.resized(withPercentage: 0.3)
    }

    for index in 0..<self.arrayTwo.count
    {
        self.arrayTwo[index].image = self.arrayTwo[index].image?.resized(withPercentage: 0.3)
    }  

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

Edit:
[Here](https://www.allaboutswift.com/dev/2016/5/21/gcd-with-qos-in-swift) the description of the different QoS.

Comment: what's the difference between `DispatchQueue.global().async ` and `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.global().async` without a specified parameter runs on 'default' qos, which according to apple is "The priority level of this QoS falls between user-initiated and utility". From that follows `DispatchQueue.global().async` has higher priority than `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async`. More info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/PrioritizeWorkWithQoS.html

Comment: @Pangu I added the description for your question