# How to create a URL for an Image using Swift

Tags: swift, url, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have used following line of code for picking an image from the Photo Library. Now I want to create a `URL`
for those images, if it's possible.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.imageView.image = image

    picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
        // Completion block
    }
}
```

How to create a `URL` for an `UIImage`?

Comment: What do you mean create url? You can get the UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL of your media asset URL 
or you can save the UIImage and use that fileURL

Comment: I need a URL for attaching an image to the local notification. I haven't any experience with the URL. Thanks for your comment. It's really useful

Comment: So you need to save your image locally. You will need to use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)` and write that data to your documents directory

Comment: I don't think you will be able to pass the asset url to the notification. You need to prepare your image (scale)

Comment: @LeoDabus It's not possible?

Comment: It is possible but you need to scale your image and save it locally

Comment: @LeoDabus Can you show me as an answer? If it's possible. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29138120/2303865 to scale your image

Comment: to save your png thumbnail https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098390/swift-png-image-being-saved-with-incorrect-orientation/42098812#42098812

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks a lot!

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Try using `let url = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! URL`

Comment: @Mannopson Did this work? If so, please mark it as accepted by pressing the check mark to the left.