# how to speed up the processing of RGB operation in a CGImage struct of macos/swift

Tags: swift, cgimage

I've got my RGB data of the CGImage. but the processing to get avrage color is so slow.
any idea? apreciated.

```swift
let screenShot:CGImage = CGDisplayCreateImage(activeDisplays[Int(index)],rect: myrect)!
let dp: UnsafePointer<UInt8> = CFDataGetBytePtr(screenShot.dataProvider?.data)
var bsum:Int = 0
var rsum:Int = 0
var gsum:Int = 0
for j in 0..<(oneH*oneW){
    rsum += Int(dp[j*4])
    gsum += Int(dp[j*4+1])
    bsum += Int(dp[j*4+2])
}
rsum/=onepack
gsum/=onepack
bsum/=onepack
```

Comment: Why don't you scale down the size of your image before calculating the average color?

Comment: pls tell me how to scale down it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29138120/2303865

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm a beginner of macos swift developing. it's an UIImage in your link. seems not defined in macos. how to process if it's a CGImage.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/jeffrafter/ad8516d4ed7221a5cfd4b66d2f7f4ca1

this is the right answer.

but I found it coast too much time.
so I dicided to sample the pixel by jumping a few rows.it's faster.