# Should I resize images from camera / photo library before sending over network?

Tags: swift, networking, swiftui, image-resizing, image-size

The images I am getting back from the photo library and camera are HUGE, and it takes a significant amount of time to send them over the network even in good conditions. I can't imagine a scenario in which I would need the full double-digit MB image, but maybe I'm missing something? Is it common practice to resize them before sending them over the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform the image into data and then use this:

```
    let imageData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
```

It will make the quality less than usual with 50% to be able to save it quickly and smoothly

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is common practice to alter an image's dimensions and compression so that it is appropriate for application.

As observed, by the default images from the camera are very large so that they can be displayed on large screens, printed to posters, zoomed and cropped etc without appearing unduly pixelated. So unless the app in question is a photo/image manipulating app, then resizing will almost certainly be beneficial in that it can improve networking, the app's memory foot-print and it's overall snappiness.

In terms of how to size and compress, while it is possible to store multiple versions of the image for each device that's being supported.

Practically, it seems that storing a single image at the dimensions required on the lowest resolution device but then only compressing it enough so that the higher resolution devices can scale up as needed without looking ugly seems to deliver reasonable results.

In terms of resizing, there are various posts on SO e.g. [How do I resize the UIImage to reduce upload image size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29137488/how-do-i-resize-the-uiimage-to-reduce-upload-image-size/29138120)

I've also stuck gist for the UIImage extension I'm currently using to do this in my App over on GitHub [here](https://gist.github.com/shufflingB/5abe77b6432cf2ab579fff405e136c7a).

Have fun.